# Входная строка имеет неверный формат

Tags: c#, конвертация

```
float num = Convert.ToSingle(ent_num.Text);
```

Пытаюсь конвертировать вводимое в текстбокс(string) значение во float, на что выдаёт ошибку, мол "Входная строка имела неверный формат". Раньше такой проблемы не наблюдал, может быть я в очердной раз туплю.
На всякий случай вот весь код:

```
 async private void ent_num_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ent_num.Text != null)
        {
            if (radioButton1.Checked) //Преобразование в 4ую СС
            {
                //await Task.Delay(1500);
                float num = Convert.ToSingle(ent_num.Text); //Введённое число

                if (num != 1)
                {
                    float result;   //Результат счёта для вывода
                    float calc = num;   //

                    while (calc <= 4)
                    {
                        result = calc % 4;
                        Test.Text = Convert.ToString(result);
                    }
                }


               //output.Text = Convert.ToString(num, 4);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так у вас бесконечный цикл. Попробуйте следующий код:

```
async private void ent_num_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ent_num.Text) && radioButton1.Checked)//Преобразование в 4ую СС
    {
        float num = Convert.ToSingle(ent_num.Text.Replace(".",",")); //Введённое число
        if (num != 1)
        {
            while (num > 4)
            {
                num = num % 4;
                Test.Text = num.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ошибка скорей всего была тут: `.Replace(".",",");`

И небольшой совет - не городите лишние переменные, они только усложняют читабельность кода.

Comment: Большое спасибо за совет и исправления. Плох, каюсь. Однако проблема осталась, всё ещё жалуется на неверный формат строки.

Comment: Кажется ответ тут: https://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-beginners/thread182318.html
Попробуйте так: Convert.ToSingle(ent_num.Text.Replace(".",","))
Поправил в ответе.

Comment: К сожалению нет, при вводе любого числа вылезае этот exception. Может что-то в форме некорректно сгенерировалось? Вообще с Windows Forms после переустановки сплошные проблемы начались, то панель элементов пустая была, то самой формы не было.

Comment: Покажите в debug'е. значение ent_num.Text в момент возникновения ошибки.

Comment: `ent_num.Text "" string` Может дело в срабатывании по нажатию, то что там KeyPress, а не KeyUp (или как оно там).

Comment: Я верно понял что у вас входная строка пустая? Добавьте проверку на пустоту - `ent_num.Text != null && ent_num.Text != ""`

Comment: @СергейТатевосян вашу проверку можно заменить более лаконично. ``string.IsNullOrEmpty("")`` или ``string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace("")``

Comment: @alladuh согласен. Поправил.

Comment: Действительно помогло, только не понятно, почему она пустая когда я ввожу в неё значения?